# How to uncheck all the checkbox by calling a function in the below dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer

Please help with this.

```
<div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{checkdata}}">
        <paper-checkbox on-tap="checkall" checked="{{item.checked}}"></paper-checkbox>
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </template>
</div>
```

properties as

```
checkdata:{
    type: Array,
    value:[{name: 'Bike'},
         {name: 'Car'},
         {name: 'Cycle'},
         {name: 'Bus'},
         {name: 'Truck'}
        ],
}
```

function as

```
checkall: function() {
    var checkvalue = this.checkdata;
    var checktext = [];
    for (i = 0; i < checkvalue.length; i++) {
        if (checkvalue[i].checked==true) {
            checktext.push(checkvalue[i].name);
            this.checkeditem = checktext + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery Plugin ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain to us [what went wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can better help you? Also, while we're at it, please do check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's considered on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How can i uncheck all the checkbox by calling a single function. Now i am not able to do that as it shows property of undefined can't be checked.

Comment: I used id in paper-checkbox and then called that id in a function to make all checkbox uncheck by making it false. It was not working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of function that you may check or uncheck :

```
checkAll() { 
          let checkdata=[];
          this.checkdata.forEach((i,x)=> {
             checkdata.push({"name": i.name, "checked": true});

             if (x==this.checkdata.length-1){
               this.set('checkdata', checkdata);
               console.log(checkdata);
            }
          })

}

uncheckAll() {
         let checkdata=[];
          this.checkdata.forEach((i,x)=> {
             checkdata.push({"name": i.name, "checked": false});

             if (x==this.checkdata.length-1){
               this.set('checkdata', checkdata);
               console.log(checkdata);
            }
          })

}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/MQeYwV?editors=1000)

Comment: This is not what I needed as i have some checkbox. The output of checkbox is shown on a dialog box if i close that dialog box all the checkbox must get untick

Comment: This above is a simple function to make untick of check box. So it is very easy to unchecked upon close of dialog box. Add this dialog box then I can connect this or you want me to do this  ?

Comment: Did you test Demo :https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/MQeYwV?editors=1000

Comment: I have a problem in displaying the value from this on paper-dialog box even if the checkbox is unchecked the value is displayed on the paper-dialog box

Answer (score 2):

Add a "$" before the equal sign of checked attribute of paper-checkbox like this:

```
<paper-checkbox on-tap="checkall" checked$="{{item.checked}}"></paper-checkbox>
```